# how to split a string with a " " delimiter?

Tags: python, string

i have a file that i created that contains counts bad ip addresses and and puts that count in front of the ip address like this:

```
      2 88.208.222.32
      3 162.209.53.127
      6 218.2.22.103
      6 218.2.22.117
    357 218.2.22.114
    462 222.186.62.23
    484 61.160.215.176
    566 60.169.74.204
    635 61.160.215.87
    659 61.160.215.64
    874 202.201.1.92
    899 61.160.215.209
    944 210.51.54.132
```

the tricky part is the spaces in front of the first field. basically my end goal is to make a loop that says "if field 1# is greater than 50, then....."
im new to python but am used to bash so im trying to learn ways to do this in python.

i thought re.split(" ") would be a good option but am unsure how to remove the first spaces. any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.split) without argument:

```
>>> '      6 218.2.22.103'.split()
['6', '218.2.22.103']
```

According to the documentation, if no argument (or `None`) is given:

> runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and
>   the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the
>   string has leading or trailing whitespace.

Comment: nice! thanks. is there a way to select the first field vs the second?

Comment: @user102825, Do you mean `first_field, second_field = '      6 218.2.22.103'.split()`?

Comment: OR, `fields = '      6 218.2.22.103'.split()`, then access `fields[0]` for the first field, `fields[1]` for the second field.

Comment: sorry, in bash i could use -d" " as a delimiter and -f1 or -f2 as field 1 and field 2 to be able to say if field 1(or the count) > 50..., just wondering if there was a way to do that

Comment: @user102825, To compare the first field with number, you need to convert it to `int` first.

Answer (score 1):

Python actually has a built-in `split` that does this by default:

```
"2 88.208.222.32".split()
>>> [2, 88.208.222.32]
```